# How to display text alignment to top, when WPF text box is a multiline

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

When i use multiline text box the text/content of text box should align to top, and if it is a single line text box then it text alignment should be default one(Center), i need to set this in text box style, so when ever there is a multiline text box my style will automatically adjust the content accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

you only need to set `VerticalContentAlignment="Top"` in your textbox like:

```
<TextBox     
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    AcceptsReturn="True" 
    Text="sample ... "
    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"                                
/>
```

Comment: If this does not work and your textbox has a custom template, make sure the ScrollViewer/ContentPresenter in the template has templatebindings to VerticalContentAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment.